# Stripe Payment Links - promo codes for non-recurring Products

Tags: stripe-payments

I have two types of products in my Stripe accounts - one which has a recurring payment model (subscription) and another which has a one time payment option. For both products, I am creating a Payment Link and providing 'allow_promotion_codes = true' on the creation call (docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create).

I have created a promo code / coupon which takes 100% off of the entire order - which is for admin/testing purposes only. This promotion code works just fine on the subscription/recurring products. However, when attempting to use the code for the one-time products, I get "The code is invalid" response.

Are promotional codes only applicable to subscriptions? Is there any way to use promo codes for one-time payment products via payment links? I would like to stick with the current model of providing payment links, hoping it's possible to add discounts to both types of products via payment links. Please do let me know if any code is needed to provide more context.

I created the coupon and payment links and the coupon in Stripe. The payment link only accepts the coupon for subscriptions and not the one-time payment products. I would expect the discount to be applied to all products.

Comment: Update - I am also following the following method to allow promotion codes for checkout sessions (instead of payment links) and I am still unable to apply the coupon for these items. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected behaviour mentioned in https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts

> Checkout does not currently support discounting a purchase below the minimum charge amount for one-time payments.

Note :  Payment Links is essentially Checkout under the hood

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the promotional codes as query string parameters to auto-apply the promotional code in the payment link as described here: https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/promotions#promotion-codes, using the "prefilled_promo_code" URL parameter.